# How to run query for each record in a dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have scenario where need to run a query for each record from a dataframe. I am running in spark-shell, Spark 1.6. I tried it like `df.rdd.map( row => sqlContext.sql("..."))`, but it is not working. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: what's the query you need to execute over each row? Reason I ask is that it will steer the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `RDD.collect` to collect the data (to the driver) and map over every row to execute an SQL query with.

```
df.rdd.collect.map(row => sqlContext.sql("..."))
```

That may or may not work given the size of the data and the memory available on the driver.

---

The reason `df.rdd.map( row => sqlContext.sql("..."))` didn't work was that you wanted to submit a query on executors as part of `map` that won't work since it has to be executed on the driver.